# Radio Button Group Doesnt not get Checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to 2 ComboBox's assigned to a group , I save True or False in Database
When I Retrieve i make the check one of the combobox as true based on my condition

But it stills shows the default value and my code doest override it . I have put this code in !IsPostback of page load

Comment: You have forgotten to show the code. Btw, double negative means the opposite, so _doesnt not get Checked_ means it gets checked.

Comment: You assigned combobox, checkbox or radio button to a group? and as Tim pointed out, Which code is not working?

Comment: Ok I Have Added the code now

Comment: if(dr.GetBoolean(12) == true)
               {
                   rbtnCancerYes. = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   rbtnCancerYes.Checked = false;
               }

Comment: sorry i coudnt edit my question

Comment: Not Sure , but u can see the code cant u ?